# Why is Eclipse/Maven (m2e) not finding source code of libraries after exceptions?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

When an exception is thrown in a library file, my Eclipse cannot find the source. See image. However, when I do F3 (Go to Definition) in my code, Eclipse does take me to the library source code.

[image: Exception, no source]

But the source exists. In my user directory is `.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\dataflow\google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all\1.7.0\google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all-1.7.0-sources.jar` and inside that is `com\google\cloud\dataflow\sdk\options\PipelineOptions.java`

When I click Edit Source Lookup Path, I note that many source-jars from  the local `.m2`  repository are listed, but not this one. See image.

So, I manually add that source-jar and rerun. See last image. But Eclipse still cannot find the source code.

How can I get Eclipse to find the source code?

I am using Eclipse 4.5.1 and m2e 1.6.2.

[image: source paths]

[image: added manually]

Comment: On the Maven project, did you try right-click > Maven > Download Sources?

Comment: Yes, I did. And the sources seem to actually be there, in the right place, as mentioned.  F3 (Go to Definition) works to get me to the code. But when there is an exception, there is no way to find the failure location.